# Aumentar la lista de clase en python se sobre escribe

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, bucles, indices

```
#lista de clases

class Persona():
__nombre=""#los guiones son para que sea un atributo privado
__apellido=""

def setNombre(self,nom):
    self.__nombre=nom
def setApellido(self,ape):
    self.__apellido=ape
def getNombre(self):
    return self.__nombre
def getApellido(self):
    return self.__apellido

print ("Tamanio de la lista: ")
n=int(input())
print("\n")

lista=[None]*n

for x in range(n):
    lista[x]=Persona()
    print("Ingrese Nombre:")
    lista[x].setNombre(input())
    print("Ingrese Apellido:")
    lista[x].setApellido(input())
    print("\n")

print("Quiere agrandar la lista?: s/n")
op=input()

if op=="s" or op=="S":
    print ("cantidad a agregar: ")
    n2=int(input())
    aux=n+n2
    for x in range(n2):
        lista.append(None)
        lista[x]=Persona()
        print("Ingrese Nombre:")
        lista[x].setNombre(input())
        print("Ingrese Apellido:")
        lista[x].setApellido(input())
        print("\n")

for x in range(aux):
    print("\nEn la posicion %d:" % x)
    print(lista[x].getNombre())
    print(lista[x].getApellido())   
#Me sobre escribe los datos de la lista, se que con append
#se escriben al final pero luego me dice 'list index out of range'
else:
    for x in range(n):
        print("\nEn la posicion %d:" % x)
        print(lista[x].getNombre())
        print(lista[x].getApellido())
```

Comment: La indentación no es correcta. Los métodos de la clase aparecen al mismo nivel que la `class`, y no está claro dónde termina la clase y empieza el "programa principal". Seguramente se debe a un error de copy&paste. Mira aqui como hacerlo para que salga bien: --> https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Answer (score 0):

Podrias resolverlo de la siguiente forma, en las lineas:

```
lista.append(None)
lista[x]=Persona()
print("Ingrese Nombre:")
lista[x].setNombre(input())
print("Ingrese Apellido:")
lista[x].setApellido(input())
print("\n")
```

Lo remplazas por esto:

```
lista.append(Persona())
print("Ingrese Nombre:")
lista[x+n].setNombre(input())
print("Ingrese Apellido:")
lista[x+n].setApellido(input())
print("\n")
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Como los rangos son dinámicos sugiero trabajar con un bucle `while` así se podrá configurar mejor el tamaño y las secciones de las listas a tomar y emplear en este caso un `break` no un `return`  para continuar luego con la pregunta de **¿quieres ampliar la lista?**

También he visto conveniente incluir, un pequeño reporte al final que permita usar los métodos `getNombre` y `getApellido` de la Clase `Persona` a fin de verificar los datos ingresados.

Adicionalmente es necesario adicionar un `def __init__(self):` a la `class Persona():` para que funcione correctamente.

El código quedaría así con sus respectivos

```
#----------------------------
# variable de inicio
# para ejecutar la
# funcion main
#----------------------------
__main__ = "main"



#----------------------------
# Clase Persona
#----------------------------
class Persona():

  def __init__(self):
        self.__nombre=""#los guiones son para que sea un atributo privado
        self.__apellido=""

  def setNombre(self,nom): self.__nombre=nom
  def setApellido(self,ape): self.__apellido=ape

  def getNombre(self): return self.__nombre
  def getApellido(self): return self.__apellido


#----------------------------
# funcion de ayuda 
# para crear lista   
#----------------------------
def crearLista(lista, n):
    end=len(lista)+n-1  # las listas empiezan en cero

    i=len(lista) # si se le llama más de una vez
                 # se garantiza que no se sobreescriba los objetos

    while (True):
        if (i>end): 
            break # se sale del bucle while
        else:
            # se agrega a la lista
            # por lo menos un elemento
            lista.append(Persona())

            #------------------------------------------
            # notese que se escribe en una lista
            # que ya tiene por lo menos un elemento (objeto)
            # entonces al usar len(lista)
            # en el caso inicial será uno (1)
            # pero Python empieza a indexar las listas
            # a partir de cero (0), en tal sentido
            # se emplea la expresion len(lista)-1
            #------------------------------------------
            print("Ingrese Nombre:")
            lista[len(lista)-1].setNombre(input())

            print("Ingrese Apellido:")
            lista[len(lista)-1].setApellido(input())

            print("\n")
            i+=1 # se actualiza contador
            #------------------------------------------


    print("Quiere agrandar la lista?: s/n")
    op=input()

    #------------------------------------------
    # en caso sea 's' o 'S'
    # se llama de nuevo a crearLista
    #------------------------------------------
    if op=="s" or op=="S":
        print ("cantidad a agregar: ")
        n2=int(input())

        #------------------------------------------
        # aux=n+n2 no es necesaria ya por lo expuesto
        # se llama de nuevo a la función crearLista
        #------------------------------------------
        crearLista(lista,n2)
        #------------------------------------------

    else:
        # se imprime un reporte y se sale de la funcion
        # con 'return' ahora sí
        for d in lista: print(d.getNombre(), d.getApellido())
        return

#----------------------------
# funcion principal
#----------------------------
def main():
    print ("Tamanio de la lista: ")
    n=int(input())
    print("\n")

    lista=[]
    crearLista(lista, n)


#----------------------------
# se llama la funcion main
#----------------------------
if __main__=="main":
    main()
```

El código anterior se puede probar en este [enlace](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user303_M090wl6VMGUp6Hx.py), sólo hay que agrandar la pantalla para que se pueda leer lo que pide el `input`.

Finalmente sugiero como ya han comentado revisar la indentación porque eso evita que el código se ejecute correctamente.